# Firing angular js animation within a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple directive along these lines:

```js
angular.module('application').directive( 'sdTitle', sdTitleDirective );

sdTitleDirective.$inject = ['$animate'];
function sdTitleDirective($animate) {
  var directive = {
    template: '<div class="title-container">some content</div>',
    link: link,
    replace: true
  };

  return directive;

  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind("click", function() {
      $animate.leave(element);
    });
  }
}
```

And an animation similar to this:

```js
angular.module('application').animation('.title-container', titleAnimation);
function titleAnimation() {
  return {
    leave: leaveAnimation
  };

  function leaveAnimation(element, done) {
    console.log('animate leave', element);
    element.hide().fadeOut(800, done);
  }

}
```

I can't seem to get the leaveAnimation to actually fire when the directive's element is clicked. I must be missing something with how $animate works or how javascript animations are called, but I'm at a loss.

How do I correctly use the $animate service's animation methods within a directive and with javascript rather than CSS3 animations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOM event handlers attached by for example `addEventListener()` or  the jqLite/jQuery methods `bind` and `on` are executed outside of the current Angular context and will not trigger the digest loop.

You will have to do it manually by using for example [$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply):

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of
>   the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events,
>   setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into
>   the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of
>   exception handling, executing watches.

Example:

```
element.bind("click", function() {
  scope.$apply(function() {
    $animate.leave(element);
  });
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/OepqBsCW25Lf2qCenbtK?p=preview

It's not apparent from your posted code if you aren't, but you need to use the ngAnimate module.

Note that in the demo I also changed:

```
element.hide().fadeOut(800, done);
```

To:

```
element.fadeOut(800, done);
```

Comment: Thanks! That definitely solves the context issue and answers the above question, though I'm struggling with this modified version where I'm trying to animate in the element as well. The enterAnimation function never seems to get called. Additionally, I'm not sure why the done() callbacks aren't executing. I don't see them in the documented method signatures for $animate.enter and $animate.leave.
"enter(element, parentElement, afterElement, [options]);"
"leave(element, [options]);"

http://plnkr.co/edit/trCJyv1wuMNNTsyics1p?p=preview

Comment: You're welcome :) I don't have time right now, but I will help you in an hour or two.

Comment: Here is a plunker with some comments: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZxrCRjLLzzCelI3JNCie?p=preview

Comment: It's of course possible to let the directive itself call $animate.enter if you need the callback.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. This definitely explains a lot about Angular and animation. The fact that a timeout is necessary at the beginning, while understandable given the internals of the digest cycle, is a bit unclear given the documentation. Thank goodness for SO. Thanks again!